# How to left align \title on general page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

I am trying to align my page's title to the left. I couldn't find a simple solution on the web to do this. Appreciate any suggestions on this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{\Huge My Sample Title \endgraf\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

Hello Latex World

\end{document}
```

Current output
[image]

Comment: You don't HAVE to use \maketitle.  It is supposed to be a convenience, not an obstacle. (\hrule will draw a line across the page.)

Comment: Thanks, I got the point. That makes it easier and gave me more control. I removed adding the bottom and top line parts from the question as I managed to solve it with {\endgraf\rule{\textwidth}{1pt} \Huge \textbf{My Sample Title} \endgraf\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}} . \hrule works too. This is a really helpful comment, could be the best answer.

Comment: The `titling` package should help.

Answer (score 2):

```
\title{\flushleft\Huge My Sample Title \endgraf\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
```

You can simply use the \flushleft as shown above.